# using spring mvc redirect a url pattern to a specific controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i would like to redirect a request something like this

localhost:8080 /firstSpringProject/{uniqueusername}

to a specific controller named 'profile':

```
@RequestMapping(value="/profile")
public String profiles(Model model){

    based on the uniqueusername i would like to render a profile page 

    return "profile";
}
```

I am using spring mvc; how can I resolve this situation is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what the source pattern is. Do you just mean something like `@RequestMapping("/{uniqueUserName}")`?

Comment: the sourece request may like this: firstSpringProject/username1 or firstSpringProject/username2 or so  and i would like to redirec that into @RequestMapping(value="/profile")  and then based on the url i would like to render user profile (here it may be username1 or 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use spring path variable here. You have to create a controller method that will take username as per your URL requirement and will redirect to profile method with username parameter.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/{username}")
    public String getUserName(Model model,@PathVariable("username") String username){

        //process username here and then redirect to ur profile method

        return "redirect : profile?username="+username;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/profile")
    public String profiles(Model model,String username){

        //have a username and render a profile page 

        return "profile";
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Spring documentation says on [redirect view](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-view):

> Note that URI template variables from the present request are
>   automatically made available when expanding a redirect URL and do not
>   need to be added explicitly neither through Model nor
>   RedirectAttributes. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/files/{path}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String upload(...) {
    // ...
    return "redirect:files/{path}";
}
```

Keep in mind that version lower than 3.1.4 are affected by a [memory leak due to caching redirect views](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10065).

If you are using Spring 3.1.3 or lower and you are doing this

```
return "redirect : profile?username="+username;
```

you will see [OutOfMemoryError sometime](http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.de/2012/12/springs-web-mvc-redirect-to-memory-leak.html).